# Using the Graph Extension Is Active Property

Tags: acumatica

If I have a new field in the baccount record call sub type, it is an integer and has description attribute. How can I use this to load or not load a specific businessaccountmaint graph extension, when the baccount record sub type is given value?

Answer (score 0):

The value of IsActive property of a graph extension is stored in the page's cache (which means it's evaluated only once at the page initialization) , so you should have the condition evaluated on true/false outside before any BAccount record is loaded in the BusinessAccountMaint graph.

IsActive works with values from setup pages, for example "Enable certain baccount type" i.e. CRSetup.UsrType1BAccount  = 1.

However, when you change the value in the setup page, the cache must be invalidated. Please note that's an expensive action with regard to performance:

```
PXDatabase.ResetSlots();
PXPageCacheUtils.InvalidateCachedPages();
```

More details here:

- https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/02/dynamically-activate-extensions.html
- https://www.acumatica.com/blog/using-modular-graph-extensions-to-avoid-mega-graphs/